# Crystal Report Running Totals between specified dates

Tags: date, crystal-reports, report

I am designing a Crystal Report for Banking where I need to publish running total between two specified dates. Now I have a problem here. See if I start from 5th of January 2012 and want to publish everything afterward, the opening balance for that calculation will start from 4th of January and before.

I have completed a report that can publish results from the start to end but not when the user specifies a report from a particular date.

Comment: can you attach a screen short or explain more.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have two parameter fields (starting_date and ending_date) that specify the date range, add this to your running-total's Evaluate formula ('Use a formula' radio button):

```
{table.date_field} IN {?starting_date} TO {?ending_date}
```